# Quick sort and setting the limit of recursion

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I have my quick sort algorithm in recursion version:

```
def quick_sort_r(some_list):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    if len(some_list) <= 1:
        return some_list
    else:
        pivot = some_list[0]
        for x in some_list:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
            else:
                equal.append(x)
        less = quick_sort_r(less)
        greater = quick_sort_r(greater)
        return greater + equal + less

def gen(number, some_list, b=100000):
    "Generating list of random numbers".
    for x in range(number):
        x = n.random.randint(b, size=1)
        some_list.extend(x)
        x=x-1

domain = [10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000]
for i in range(len(domain)):
    print 'Results for: ' + str(domain[i]) + ' elements:'
    for j in range(0,10):
        list=[]
        gen(dziedzina[i], list)
        start = time.time()
        quick_sort_r(list)
        end = time.time() - start
        print end
    print '*************************'
```

Yes it should be in recursion version and yes it should be descending sort.

Of course I have this classic error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Is there any possible limit to generate this results for this domain? I know about:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(x)
```

Comment: It's highly doubted that there's some mistake in your implement. `log_2(100000)` shall be far lower than the maximum level of recursion depth.

Comment: Also, don't override keywords like this: `list=[]`

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `"Generating list of random numbers".` is not valid syntax. And `time`, `n`, and `dziedzina` are not defined.

Comment: @starrify, I agree that quicksort recurses `log2(len(list))` times in the best case scenario. But in the worst case, it can recurse `len(list)-1` times. Namely, if the lowest number is picked for the pivot every time. That would happen here when you try to sort an already sorted list.

Comment: @starrify that would hold only in the *average* case and *with a random pivot*. The OP is always taking the first element as pivot which means that when the input is sorted you have a worst-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few mistakes with your code which might have lead to the recursion issues.

1. You were overriding the built-in datatype 'list'.
2. Your gen method was actually trying to create list of lists, instead of creating list of random numbers.

A few suggestion too:

1. You should be reading into list comprehensions. :)
2. You could use the timeit module for checking the time taken to complete your method execution.

The below code works as expected, if this is what you wanted to do.

```
import random
import time


def quick_sort_r(some_list):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    # print some_list
    if len(some_list) <= 1:
        return some_list
    else:
        pivot = some_list[0]
        for x in some_list:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
            else:
                equal.append(x)
        less = quick_sort_r(less)
        greater = quick_sort_r(greater)
        return greater + equal + less


def gen(number, b=100000):
    "Generating list of random numbers"
    some_list = []
    return [some_list.append(random.randint(0, b)) for x in xrange(number)]

domain = [10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000]
for element in domain:
    print 'Results for: ' + str(element) + ' elements:'
    for j in range(0, 10):
        temp_list = gen(element)
        start = time.time()
        quick_sort_r(temp_list)
        end = time.time() - start
        print end
    print '*************************'
```

Comment: This still crashes for big already-sorted lists. Try changing `gen` to `return range(number)`, and see.

Comment: Saw the issue. Seems like we might need to break it into smaller lists, sort and then join. Basically, a modified version of the quick_sort. :)

Comment: But then it wouldn't be quick sort, it would be merge sort!